# how to dynamically query database via web?

Tags: java, node.js, odata, breeze, business-intelligence

Can you recommend on a framework which enable querying of data via web?

Requirements:

1. **ORM capabilities** - I want that the representation of the model at the server & client *will not be dependent*.
   For example: let's say that the server will return to the client layer the following model: transaction (firstName, lastName, description, amount). While in the dal-layer it's being saved like this: Customer(Id, fName, lName, address) , Transaction(id, CustomerId, description, amount)
2. **Option to write my own query provider** (For example: HiveQL, SQL & etc).

I have tried to use the following frameworks (but it's seems like it, that the first demand is not supported):

1. **JayData:** http://jaydata.org/
2. **breezejs:** http://www.breezejs.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Breeze does provide this but you will need to write the server side code that translates an OData query into a query that your chosen server implements.  We already provide several implementations of this code for different server/database technologies and plan on doing more in the future.

To date we have done this for .NET servers with both Entity Framework and NHibernate ORM's and against  Node servers with MongoDB backends.  We also have other developers working on a Ruby server implementation.  If you want to write your own, you should probably take a look at the Breeeze/MongoDB source to see how this is done.

Alternately, if your chosen server tech already has an OData provider, then Breeze can talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

OData does provide a way to query database via web, such as

```
GET http://myservice/Products?$filter=Id gt 3 and contains(Name,'abc')
GET http://myservice/Products?$select=Id,Name,Provider&$orderby=ManufactureDate desc
```

Here are some odata samples https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/. In a controller, you can use what ever framework/provider you like to retrieve data from persistence.

If you want to use Entity Framework please follow this one:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataActionsSample/.